# NFS mount shows root directory after some time

Tags: 17.10, automount, nfs, autofs

I have some NFS4 shares mounted via autofs. 
E.g. `/mnt/autofs/MyPictures`
When I navigate in this directory, e.g., going to `/mnt/autofs/MyPictures/2017-01/partyWithHugh`, after some time, Nautilus shows again the root folder (`/mnt/autofs/MyPictures`).
Why is that and how can I prevent this?

```
$ nautilus --version
GNOME nautilus 3.26.0

$ less /etc/auto.master
+auto.master
/mnt/autofs     /etc/auto.nfs   --ghost

$ less /etc/auto.nfs
MyPictures   -fstype=nfs4,rw,soft,intr,async,noatime 192.168.0.107:/MyPictures
```

Comment: Easiest way: In `auto.master` add the option `-t 0` to the line `/mnt/autofs`; this will disable expiration of the mount. Or change to some othervalue (in seconds; see `man auto.master`. And you should move the line `+auto.master` to the end of the file (well, it really doesn't matter, as you won't use NIS, do you?).

Comment: I dont use NIS. Would be nice, though. The 0-timeout will also affect mounts that are not available? I assume a mount that is not available anymore will still show up when there is no timeout?

Comment: The timeout set with the ` auto.master` entry is the _expiration timeout_, what means that after having being idle for that seconds (i.e., no access to the mounted share) there is an automatic `unmount`. This has nothing to do with the availability of the server; if the server dies before the `expiration timeout`, the attempt to access the share will as well hang the program. To avoid this (as far as possible),  you might have to use appropriate NFS options in `auto.nfs`. The _ expiration timeout_ is just used to save ressources (network and server) if the mount is no longer used.

Comment: If you want to avoid the behaviour of Nautilus (falling back to the root folder, i.e. the (unmounted) mountpoint, you may create some links somewhere (e.g. in your home folder: `ln -s /mnt/autofs/MyPictures/ .`. If you access that from Nautilus, the automount should take place and not fall back (well, this is just my experience).

Comment: OK, guess its clear now. So setting the *expiration timeout* to 0 will do exactly what I want, and will not effect availability (which I am trying to address with `soft,intr,async,noatime`).

Comment: I would accept your comments as an answer ;) thanks a lot!